# How to convert json array to json?

Tags: arrays, json, apex-code, apex

I am New to APEX programming language.I am having JSON Array string i only need to convert it into JSON Object i.e I need to remove [] from the array.
Example:

```
[{"Attributes":
 {"Type":"Account","url";"/servicec/data/v4.0"},"LastModified":"2017-05-05"}]
```

I need to Convert Above Json Array to

```
{"Attributes":
{"Type":"Account","url";"/servicec/data/v4.0"},"LastModified":"2017-05-05"}
```

Comment: I don't have idea about apex programing but if there is array of object then you you can access object within that array by using index. like `[{"Attributes": {"Type":"Account","url":"/servicec/data/v4.0"},"LastModified":"2017-05-05"}][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Object> arr =(List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
String firstemement = arr[0];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Shouldn't the function name be **deserializeUntyped**. Looks like you have put an unwanted 's' in the function name.

Comment: Made the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the deserialize method in Apex JSON class :

```
String jsonInput = [{"Attributes": {"Type":"Account","url";"/servicec/data/v4.0"},
                      "LastModified":"2017-05-05"}];
Map<String, Object> array = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
String firstElt = array[0];
```

The documentation is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the Help it Helped me.
I used List instead of Map because it was giving me an error for Map.

Comment: can I know the meaning of deserializeUntyped